# Joining nichrome wire within 1140 celsius kiln

Tags: voltage, power, current, resistance, heat

I am trying to join 2.5mm diameter nichrome wire in my wife’s pottery kiln (1200 degrees celsius.)

I can’t find nichrome inline crimps, copper crimps won’t last. I am resorting to a steel bolt compression join as I think steel bolts(6mm or 1/4 inch) won’t melt.  I just need conductivity 240VAC, but am not sure if there is an alternative to replacing the whole element.

Maybe someone has tried this before. It doesn’t have to look pretty but must maintain electro/mechanical strength, it runs about 10 amps, but 1200 celsius

Answer (score 0):

The bulk conductivity of steel is not your problem, it will be far better than nichrome. However at 1200 C, it will oxidise fast and you'll lose the metal surface. You need to use an alloy that will withstand the temperature without surface oxidation. Maybe stainless steel? If you can use it to hold one nichrome wire in contact with the other, you may get away with it.

Comment: Surely if the crimp is 'tight' enough then air would be unable to reach the contact surfaces and oxidation wouldn't be an issue? Only the exposed surfaces would oxidize.

Comment: Surely the OP was asking about bolts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sleeve of copper, or a tiny copper tube. You do crimp with a press this sleeve. Since the copper has low resistance it won't heat, so you can connect this sleeve to a terminal block outside and then with silicone cable.

However if the melting point of copper isn't enough, you can use a different metal, for example beryllium copper, stainless steel,...but these material is hard, so you would need a hydraulic crimping tool.